# Query to get database log file size

Tags: mysql, sql, oracle, db2, sap-iq

I need the queries for all databases e.g. `SQL`, `Oracle`, `MySql`, etc to get the log file size like for SQl server.

```
SELECT * FROM sys.database_files
```

Can anyone help me to find queries for all the databases?

Comment: MySql-> select @@datadir;

Answer (score 0):

In Oracle log file size can be checked here:

```
select * from v$log;
```

Answer (score 0):

In DB2, the (transaction) log file size can be obtained from

```
select name, varchar(value, 32) 
  from SYSIBMADM.DBCFG 
  where name = 'logfilsiz'
```

And you get

```
NAME                             2
-------------------------------- --------------------------------
logfilsiz                        4096
  1 record(s) selected.
```

That means 4096 pages of 4096KB ~= 16 MB